# When I try to edit my pages it gives me 404 error page after I click save

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So When I try to edit any of my pages or change theme options in my wp admin panel and click save it gives me 404 error page most of the time especially If I made more than one change. I don't know if it has anything to do with it but I've just increased my server memory in the .htaccess

Comment: don't have enough info to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you do not have any errors in and that you did not delete the WordPress code from your `.htaccess` file.

You can try to reset your permalinks by going to `Settings > Permalinks` and clicking **Save Changes**. In doing this WordPress will attempt to rebuild the chunk of `.htaccess` that is needed for the permalinks.